# Testing TLS security in WCF-netTCPBinding

Tags: wcf, ssl, .net-4.0, wireshark

I'm developing a client/server Winforms application. Clients connect to server using internet and use WCF's netTCPBinding to talk to server.

- Communicating in a secure channel is very important for me and since [NetTCP binding is secured by default with TLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731172.aspx), it seems like I don't have to do anything. Do I?
- How can I *monitor* the encrypted data sent/received between my client/server in localhost? I used [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) to capture data and opened the dump file in Wireshark. But I don't know how I should check for TLS security in packets. dump file is full of unkown TCP packets (not from my software) with `vcom=tunnel` info for most of them.

Comment: Why are you monitoring content of the messages?

Comment: I'm not. I'm trying to find out how to actually see the data transferring between my client/server and make sure it's encrypted/signed

Comment: Your service requirement is to use Transport security. If TLS cannot be negotiated service will reject calls from the client hence you are guaranteed that both client and service have to comply with TLS requirement.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks. Though still curious about my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP binding security element is set to Transport by default. This indicates requirement that transport session must be encypted. If you cannot establish TLS session service will reject the call.

You can use something like [TCPMon](http://code.google.com/p/tcpmon/) which will show TLS traffic albeit encrypted. Also there is [SSLDump](http://www.rtfm.com/ssldump/)